# How to run setup code before any tests run in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I have a Rust app (a simple interpreter) that needs some setup (initialize a repo) before the environment is usable.

I understand that Rust runs its tests (via cargo test) in a multithreaded manner, so I need to initialize the repo before any tests run. I also need to do this only once per run, not before each test.

In Java's JUnit this would be done with a @BeforeClass (or @BeforeAll in JUnit 5) method. How can I acheive the same thing in Rust?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's nothing built-in that would do this but this should help (you will need to call `initialize()`  in the beginning of every test):

```
use std::sync::Once;

static INIT: Once = Once::new();

pub fn initialize() {
    INIT.call_once(|| {
        // initialization code here
    });
}
```

Comment: I have error when using this code. Error: "static INIT: Once = Once::new();  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default".
Please help me to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @TheSun you need to call it before every test as Jussi suggested

Comment: @yerlilbilgin thank you, I solved my problem by using lazy_static

Comment: more explanation or links would be useful

Answer (score 53):

If you use the [ctor](https://docs.rs/ctor/) crate, you can take advantage of a global constructor function that will run before any of your tests are run.

Here's an example initialising the popular [env_logger](https://docs.rs/env_logger/) crate (assuming you have added `ctor` to your `[dev-dependencies]` section in your `Cargo.toml` file):

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[ctor::ctor]
fn init() {
    env_logger::init();
}
```

The function name is unimportant and you may name it anything.

Comment: I should put this into each `.rs` file?

Comment: @yegor256 Every test file is a different executable program, so yes. But you could also create a [common module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#submodules-in-integration-tests) so that you only need to define it once

Answer (score 27):

Just to give people more ideas (for example, how not to call `setup` in every test), one additional thing you could do is to write a helper like this:

```
fn run_test<T>(test: T) -> ()
    where T: FnOnce() -> () + panic::UnwindSafe
{
    setup();    
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        test()
    });    
    teardown();    
    assert!(result.is_ok())
}
```

Then, in your own tests you would use it like this:

```
#[test]
fn test() {
    run_test(|| {
        let ret_value = function_under_test();
        assert!(ret_value);
    })
}
```

You can read more about `UnwindSafe` trait and `catch_unwind` here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html

I've found the original idea of this test helper in [this medium article](https://medium.com/@ericdreichert/test-setup-and-teardown-in-rust-without-a-framework-ba32d97aa5ab) by Eric Opines.

Also, there is [rstest](https://github.com/la10736/rstest) crate which has [pytest-like](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest) fixtures which you can use as a setup code (combined with the [Jussi Kukkonen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58006287/3606603):

```
use std::sync::Once; 
use rstest::rstest;
static INIT: Once = Once::new();

pub fn setup() -> () { 
    INIT.call_once(|| {
        // initialization code here
    });
}

#[rstest]
fn should_success(setup: ()) {
    // do your test
}
```

Maybe one day rstest will gain scopes support and `Once` won't be needed anymore.

Comment: Nice tech work, but too much barebones for running a test..

Comment: `rstest` does have the `#[once]` attribute macro for `#[fixture]` functions - but I think it still uses statics under the covers (i.e. no/unreliable drop)