# How to create and drop a shared resource for tests?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

A subset of my tests need a resource that is only allowed to be created once.
This resource also has to be dropped at some point (not before the last test needing it finished).

Currently I use a static OnceCell:

```rust
struct MyResource {}

impl Drop for MyResource {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropped MyResource");
    }
}

impl MyResource {
    fn new() -> MyResource {
        println!("Created MyResource");
        MyResource {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _my_resource = MyResource::new();
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use tokio::sync::OnceCell;

    static GET_RESOURCE: OnceCell<MyResource> = OnceCell::const_new();

    async fn init_my_resource() {
        GET_RESOURCE.get_or_init(|| async {
            MyResource::new()
        }).await;
    }

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn some_test() {
        init_my_resource().await;
        assert_eq!("some assert", "some assert");
    }
}
```

This works fine except that it never drops the resource.

Is there a better way to do this that also drops the resource?

The answer to [How to run setup code before any tests run in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58006033/how-to-run-setup-code-before-any-tests-run-in-rust) does not answer this question as it only answers how to initialize something once, but not how to drop something after the tests ran.

Comment: I can't seem to find an associated function of `OnceCell` called `const_new`. There is `new`, which is also `const`, so that's maybe what you meant? Also, I can't get to compile your code because it complains about `OnceCell<_>` not being `Sync`.

Comment: @BlackBeans Sorry, I forgot to add a use statement. I'm using tokio's variant of OnceCell.

Comment: Incidentally, the question you link to also provides the solution to your question. The suggested crate, `ctor`, also provides a similar functionality but for running finish code after all your tests are run.

Comment: Thanks that solves it. :)

Comment: If that solves it, I'll just add it as an answer for future readers :)

Comment: The one time I  used a crate built on top of Tokio, I decided to stay clear of *Tokio* as it is simply too invasive and monopolizes otherwise unrelated code with its "voodoo".  Not even `main()` remains unaffected, nor as it shows here, unit tests. Its like a virus, spreading the infection and it is hard to keep it in a dedicated part of a larger project. As such, I consider it terrible design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight-forward solution I found is offered by the crate static_init:

```
struct MyResource {}

impl Drop for MyResource {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropped my rescource");
    }
}

impl MyResource {
    fn new() -> MyResource {
        println!("Created MyResource");
        MyResource {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _my_resource = MyResource::new();
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use static_init::dynamic;

    #[dynamic(drop)]
    static mut RES: MyResource = MyResource::new();

    #[tokio::test]
    async fn some_test() {
        println!("Running test");
        assert_eq!("some assert", "some assert");
    }
}
```

Another proposed solution was using ctor and dtor of the crate ctor. Though using this with a plain `static mut RES: MyResource` results in unsafe code as we need to modify a mutable static.

Answer (score 1):

The crate [ctor](https://docs.rs/ctor/latest/ctor/index.html) provides the `dtor` macro, which allows you to manually `drop` the resources once all your tests are done.

Comment: As noted in my answer I think the solution with static_init is better as it doesn't need unsafe. (At least when directly using it without extra precautions)
But thank you anyways for this proposal.